# Open iOS app from facebook app when tap on app name in shared url post or link

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, hyperlink

The main problem is that when user tap in facebook app on app name from which was made an post, need to open the app, this works fine for instagram app.

[image: Exaple how it's works with instagram share]

**But this not work with my app**

I can login with facebook, make posts, likes, and share links, app is registered on facebook and approved same workflow works fine in android app but not in iOS

This is how my url schemes and types looks like in my app info.plist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed with turn on Single Sign On in facebook app settings and after will appear the option Deep Linking and also need to activate it.

[image]

Comment: Hello. I can not find this options, how can you find it?